# Facebook login public key

Tags: android, facebook-login, social-media

I have integrated login with Facebook feature into my app. I used a debug key. As a result, only I can log into my app with my Facebook account. But other people can't login into my app using their facebook account. It requires a public key.

**Now my question is**: How can I get that public key?

[image: Facebook login error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Facebook Developer Console and select your application.
2. Move to **Status & Review**.
3. Toggle the button from **no** to **yes**.
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any public key. Just go to your app in your Facebook Developer Account and make your app **public**. You can find the option in **Settings**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first generate signet apk than use this on your signet apk location

```
keytool -exportcert -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore
  | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Comment: thank u...but a i have a problem with how to use that key...my android studio is still using the debug key...although i have provided the release key to the enter release key section in the "Add your development and release key hashes"  part...